# Is my power consumption measurement tool broken?

Tags: electrical, home-theater

In order to optimize power consumption of my home theater setup, I'm using a power consumption tool (similar to [this one](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07CWRBPH7)) at the main single power socket where everything is plugged in via extensions.

My base standby is around 50W which I think is quite high, but it's also 10 machines being plugged in.

In search of the main standby consumers, I plug in and out various devices.

With one device, notably Playstation 5, the behaviour is very irritating. The console is turned off. If I plug it **out**, total consumption of the setup is **going up** by 10W. I plug it in again, total measured consumption is going down again.

I don't see that with any other devices being plugged in or out.

How is this even possible? Can a measurement tool be broken in such a weird way?

Comment: When playstation is plugged out, is it only at the plug, or all connections?

Comment: AC power is... complicated. Watts are not volt-amps, power factor and reactance must be considered.

Comment: the PS5's removal from power could cause an hdmi input's device to enter a more power-hungry active scan/wait mode than the sleep mode a connected device can trigger. Same for auto-off subwoofers, etc; something plugged in keeps it asleep, but "floating" the input keeps it awake by design or electrical. noise.

Answer (score 3):

I think 50W standby is *outrageous*, but the largest US cable company's cable box used to have that much *alone*.

Ecnerwal's "wake up" theory is the best answer in my book.  The problem is, there's a difference between "watts" and "VA" ... "VA" is the whole sine wave, "watts" is the part of the sine wave the device actually uses. **A lot of electronic devices have poor power-factor** (watts/VA), and so when you add them together, weird stuff can happen to VA, as one device may scavenge the parts of the sine wave that the other device is wasting.

To deep-drill more into that, AC is a varying current, going from 0 to [ line voltage x 1.4142136 ] and back in a sine wave.   A device that draws X amps with a power factor of perfection/unity/1.0, will draw current in perfect proportion - going from 0 to [ X amps x 1.4142136 ] in a sine wave, current matching voltage per Ohm's Law.  However electronic devices kinda "do what they want". Some draw power at the beginning of the wave until they're "full up"... old fashion rectifier power supplies only draw from the center of the wave. Etc.

VA and Amps are specified as "this device never exceeds a current draw that a *resistive load* (PF 1.0) would draw if it was that many amps or watts".  **Suppose you take a 1000 W / 1000 VA heater** (a 'perfect' resistor) and add a diode so it only uses half the sine wave.  It only gives 500 watts of heat, but it still takes 1000 VA (power factor 0.5)... because you must *generate and deliver* the entire sine wave, even if only half is used.

*LED Christmas lights work like this.  They have ~35 LED's in series, with a blocking diode, so they light half the time.*

If you had two of those heaters, they'd each be 1000 VA and together 2000 VA.  But if you flipped one of the plugs over, each one would use the opposite half of the sine wave, so the whole sine wave would get used evenly, giving a power factor of 1.0.  Measuring both together would show only 1000 VA.

*LED Christmas lights with several sections work like this. Every other section is opposite polarity, to even out VA/power factor*.

Anyway, power measuring devices *have to deal with all this madness*.   Reputable ones like the Kill-A-Watt actually take thousands of on-the-fly measurements per second, so they can accurately distinguish VA from Watts. Cheap ones make assumptions, and will not read correctly for devices with poor power factor.

Your best bet is make sure you have a quality unit and not a knock-off. Your second best bet is measure each appliance *individually*.

Comment: Those 50 are for an AVR, a subwoofer, a sonos connect and a LAN switch and then some; but without the TV... I will try measuring devices each by themself. And thank you for the detailled answer!

Answer (score 1):

Probably something that's "asleep" is being "woken up" by the playstation going away. That might or might not go back to "sleep" if you leave it 15 minutes or so (possibly less.) You can figure out which one (or ones) by unplugging the playstation **and** another device. *Alternatively, plug in ONLY the playstation, and I'll just about guarantee that the power consumption will **not** become negative when you unplug it.*

**Regardless:** If the standby consumption is a concern, use a power strip and turn it off, dealing with whatever startup delays are incurred by not having whatever thinks it needs to burn power when "off" burning power.

Comment: The Playstation is only being plugged in, not turned on at all when this happens. I already have one main power strip for all devices, but some of them I use only rarely and would like to optimize that even more. OTH, the OLED TV must be able to do some pixel repair processes in standby and must not be turened off completely all the time.

Comment: Sure. But something else sees the "not turned on playstation" as an input (most likely) that wants it to sleep, since that input is not turned on. Unplug it, and instead of registering as "not turned on" it registers as "nothing" and the device in question wakes up looking for inputs.